# How to add input fields into a list in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a beginner in React Native ans struggling with adding Input (Search bars) into a list by clicking a button. Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    FlatList
} from 'react-native'
import InputDemo from '../components/InputDemo'

const INCREMENT = 1;

class AddInputDemo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            counter: 0,
            numOfInput: [0]
        }
        this.addInput = this.addInput.bind(this)
    }

    addInput(){
        this.setState((state) => ({
            counter: state.counter + INCREMENT,
            numOfInput: [...state.numOfInput, state.counter]
        }))

        console.log(this.state.counter);
        console.log(this.state.numOfInput);



    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.numOfInput}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                    renderItem={itemData => {
                        <InputDemo/>
                    }}
                />
                <Button title='Add a location' onPress={this.addInput} />

            </View>
        );
    }

}

export default AddInputDemo;
```

Here's the **InputDemo** file:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    Button
} from 'react-native'

const InputDemo = props => {
    return(
        <View style={{borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1}}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder='Search'
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default InputDemo;
```

It's weird since I use this same logic with state in `Functional Component`. It works. But when applying to a `Class Component`, it does not show anything when I click that button.

THANKS FOR ANY HELP !!!

**EDIT**
I tried to use extraData:

```
<FlatList
                    extraData={this.state.numOfInput}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                    renderItem={itemData => {
                        <InputDemo
                            id={itemData.item.id}
                        />
                    }}
                />
```

And created an id for each InputDemo:

```
const InputDemo = props => {
    return(
        <View key={props.id} style={{borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1}}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder='Search'
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

**But it still does not work**
**Please help !!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2**
Hi guys, I know where the error is now. It's not about the data or extraData. The solution is we have to wrap around the `<InputDemo/>` with a `return` statement. It works well then. Thank you all for the helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass [extraData](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata)

> A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements PureComponent). If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.numOfInput}
    extraData={counter}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    renderItem={itemData => (
        <InputDemo/>
    )}
/>
```

## Edit:

You also have a huge problem, your `data` don't have `.id` prop and `keyExtractor` probably isn't working.

You could change it to

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

But this still isn't good, try adding unique `id` prop to each item.

Comment: you mean replace data with extraData ?
Since, InputDemo doesn't have anything extra props. It's just a ```<TextInput/>``` component

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've tried but it still doesn't work. I tried to pass a key for the view in ```InputDemo```. And used: ```extraData={this.state.numOfInput}```. The screen still shows nothing. Please help

Answer (score 1):

FlatList data attribute takes prop as Array. Documentation is your bestfriend.
Everything goes more or less like below, not tested but closer to what you want, I hope.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    FlatList
} from 'react-native'
import InputDemo from '../components/InputDemo'

const INCREMENT = 1;


class AddInputDemo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            counter: 0,
            numOfInput: [0],
            item:'',
            searchArray:[],

        }
        this.addInput = this.addInput.bind(this)
    }


    addInput(){

        this.setState((state) => ({
            counter: state.counter +=1,
            searchArray:[...this.state.searchArray, this.state.item] //appends search item to search array
            numOfInput: [...state.numOfInput, state.counter]  //don't know why you need this
        }))

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>

           <InputDemo search={(searchItem)=>this.setState({item:searchItem})}/>     
           <FlatList
                    data={this.state.searchArray}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                    renderItem={itemData => {
                        <Text>{itemData}</Text>
                    }}
                />
                <Button title='Add a location' onPress={this.addInput} />

            </View>
        );
    }

}

export default AddInputDemo;
```

And Input Demo

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {
    View,
     TextInput
} from 'react-native'

const InputDemo = props => {


   const onChangeText = (item) => {
         props.search(item);  //add search item to state of "class AddInputDemo" using props
      }
    return(
        <View style={{borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1}}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder='Search'
                onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default InputDemo;
```